# counter in map() functions does not work, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter, map-function

I have a problem. It seems that my counter does not work and does not change to 1, so my questioncontext variable is always "Fragekontext0" for every item in the map function. Do you know why? Here is the code:

```
Object.keys(editorJSON).map((key) => {
  let questioncounter = 0;
  if (editorJSON[key].name === "Frage") {
    let questioncontext = "Fragekontext" + questioncounter;
    someCode
    );
  }
  questioncounter += 1;
  return "Success";
});
```

};

Comment: Why should it be anything other than `0`? `questioncounter` is part of the callback. Either move it outside the callback, or use the index (second argument of the callback) instead.

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` (which you are obviously not, at least in your example with a built-in syntax error), then `.map()` is not the right tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new `questioncounter` variable is declared in every map callback function. To have each callback access the same `questioncounter` variable, place `let questioncounter = 0;` outside the map function.